# Swift matching elements within nested array of structs

Tags: ios, swift

I'm a Swift newbie and I'm trying to get to grips with the following data structure. I have an array (`categories`) of `category` structs. Each `category` struct contains an array of `business` structs stored as a value on the property `items`. I'm not sure how to represent this kind of thing but hopefully this pseudo-code makes it a little bit clearer:

```
categories: [category]
   - category: Struct
        .categoryId: Int
        .items: [business]
            - business: Struct
               .busId: Int
            - business: Struct
               .busId: Int
   - category: Struct
        .categoryId: Int
        .items: [business]
            - business: Struct
               .busId: Int
            - business: Struct
               .busId: Int
```

Given a `busId` I'm trying to return a matching `business` Struct and the `categoryId` in which it is contained. I've tried using FlatMap and Map but I'm going round in circles trying to unwrap and filter this data structure.

Any pointers/advice about approaches to take would be great.

Comment: Could you write the structure in swift literal syntax for us to more easily use?

Comment: @AMomchilov - I'm happy to do anything that helps but I'm afraid I don't know what you mean :-( Shall I post the Struct classes? (I was trying to keep it simple :-p )

Comment: By Swift literal syntax as in anArray = [1, 2, 3], aDict = ["a" : 1], etc.

Comment: @James: Can a `Business` appear in more then 1 `Category`?

Comment: @appzYourLife That's a gotcha I thought of earlier. For this use case I think it'll be fine to use the first category in which they appear.

Comment: ...BTW. I'm just working with @AMomchilov 's answer below ...definitely gets the right category...I'm just trying to extract the rest of the info...will post solution/comments (& up votes!) when I've got a bit further. Thanks

Comment: this seems like it should be a bidirectional relationship. A business should stores the category it belongs to. It'll make this much easier

Comment: @AMomchilov :-) Yes! I agree...that would make it much easier...I need to see if I can change the way records are added to this structure.

Comment: I overlooked the need to return the business struct =/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Given a Business struct defined like this

```
struct Business {
    let busID: Int
}
```

### A Category like this

```
struct Category {
    let categoryID: Int
    let business: [Business]
}
```

### And a list of Category

```
let categories = [
    Category(categoryID: 0, business: [Business(busID:0)]),
    Category(categoryID: 1, business: [Business(busID:1), Business(busID:2)])
]
```

### We can extract the categoryID and the Business having a given Int

```
func search(businessID: Int, categories: [Category]) -> (categoryID: Int, business:Business)? {
    let res = categories.reduce([Int:Business]()) { (res, category) ->  [Int:Business] in
        guard res.isEmpty else { return res }
        var res = res
        if let business = (category.business.filter { $0.busID == businessID }).first {
            res[category.categoryID] = business
        }
        return res
    }

    guard let categoryID = res.keys.first, business = res[categoryID] else  { return nil }
    return (categoryID, business)
}
```

### Example

[image]

### Update

This is a shorter version which does not use `reduce`

```
func search(businessID: Int, categories: [Category]) -> (categoryID: Int, business:Business)? {
    guard let
        category = (categories.filter { $0.business.contains { $0.busID == businessID } } ).first,
        business = (category.business.filter { $0.busID == businessID } ).first
    else { return nil }
    return (category.categoryID, business)
}
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much. I was busy working with @AMomchilov's great answer below when this arrived. This is exactly what I was after. However, there's lots in your answer I wasn't aware of (e.g. I didn't know about reduce). I'll definitely try to learn more about reduce, map and flatMap as it seems to be holding me back. Thanks again for such an amazing answer :-)

Comment: @James: If you want to avoid the `reduce` you can use the new version of `search` I just added to my answer.

Comment: @James for the record, there's nothing reduce, map, flatMap and filter do that for loops can't. They just make it simpler in many (but not all!) cases

Comment: @AMomchilov: I agree: they are simply high level tools.

Comment: Yay!! I've got it working beautifully using the original (reduce) answer. Thanks for your comments about reduce etc - I'm going spend more time learning about this stuff as I clearly have got my brain in a muddle about it. Thank to you and @AMomchilov for taking the time to help out...I'm very grateful indeed.

Answer (score 1):

How's this?

```
categories.filter{category in //filter the categories as the final result
    category.items //get the Businesses in the category
            .map{$0.busId} //get the busIds of the Businesses
            .contains(desiredBusinessID) //keep iff the desired busId is present
}
```